# How to pass XMPPTCPConnection object between two Activities in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, xmpp, smack

I want to pass a XMPPTCPConnection object with `intent.putExtra(...);` but unfortunately it didn't work with casting my object to `Serialize` or `Parcelable` like: `signInIntent.putExtra("connection", (Serialize) conn);` and reporting the error : "can not cast `XMPPTCPConnection` to `Serialize` or `Parcelable`." 
i see many similar questions and try to do like their answers.
so i tried to add the object to a list and then pass that list.
this is my first Activity :

```
Intent signInIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
ArrayList<XMPPTCPConnection> conn = new ArrayList<XMPPTCPConnection>();
conn.add(connection);
signInIntent.putExtra("connection",  conn);
startActivity(signInIntent);
```

and this is my second Activity :

```
Bundle getData = getIntent().getExtras(); 
List<XMPPTCPConnection> listConn = new ArrayList<>();
listConn = (List<XMPPTCPConnection>) getData.get("connection");
XMPPTCPConnection connection = listConn.get(0);
```

but this error reported :

```
12-27 18:48:42.919 30358-30358/finalproject.ffisher.com.finalproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-27 18:48:42.919 30358-30358/finalproject.ffisher.com.finalproject E/AndroidRuntime: Process: finalproject.ffisher.com.finalproject, PID: 30358
12-27 18:48:42.919 30358-30358/finalproject.ffisher.com.finalproject E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection@3f8f8920
```

am I wrong in this code ?
is there any other way to pass data between activities ?
please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest to keep your `XMPPTCPConnection` object in in `Application`'s extension, as it's accessible from any place within the app.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private XMPPTCPConnection connection;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public void initializeXMPPTCPConnection() {
        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
            .setServiceName(SERVER_HOST)
            .setHost(SERVER_ADDRESS)
            .setPort(PORT)
            .setCompressionEnabled(false)
            .setResource("test")
            .setDebuggerEnabled(true)
            .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
            .build();
        connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
    }

    public XMPPTCPConnection getXMPPTCPConnection() {
        return connection;
    }
}
```

And in `AndroidManifest` add reference to it:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication" />
```

Then you can call `((MyApplication)getApplication()).initializeXMPPTCPConnection();` or `((MyApplication)getApplication()).getXMPPTCPConnection();` from any activity you want

Comment: what is exactly an extention and how can I do that ?

Comment: @Fisher  see this tutorial as an example: http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/  . Anyway, I updated my answer with actual code you can use.

Comment: @KonstantinLoginov i followed you answer and i getting MyApplication.initializeXMPPTCPConnection()' on a null object reference error, what i missing ?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer from above, i had the same issue and indeed there is a null exception error. Do not use the second method and change the first. Instead of void use

`public XMPPTCPConnection initializeXMPPTCPConnection(){}`

and in the end of the method
`return connection;`

when you need to call it, do it like
`XMPPTCPConnection con =
 ((MyApplication)getApplication()).initializeXMPPTCPConnection();`

And use `con` to `connect()` and `login()`.